# Invoking ranges::for_each with lambda and global function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, range-v3

The following code works as expected:

```
void foo(auto const &){}

auto const rng{ranges::view::all(v)};
ranges::for_each(rng, [](auto const & r){
    foo(r);
});
```

But the following:

```
void foo(auto const &){}

auto const rng{ranges::view::all(v)};
ranges::for_each(rng, &foo);
```

Gives the compilation error:

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
couldn't deduce template parameter 'F'
```

I took a look at the [source](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/algorithm/for_each.hpp) but to be honest I couldn't understand the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot take the address of an *overloaded* or *template* function by without explicitly specifying the overload/instantiation you desire.

Passing a *lambda expression* as in your first snippet is a good solution to this issue.

Alternatively, if you have access to `foo`, you could turn it into a *function object*:

```
namespace detail
{
    struct foo_t
    {
        template <typename T>
        void operator()(const T&) const { /* ... */ }
    };
}

constexpr detail::foo_t foo{};
```

This allows you to write:

```
ranges::for_each(rng, foo);
```

Comment: Oh. The function has `auto` as a parameter type. That went totally out of my head. So my question has nothing with `rangesv3`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A function name doesn't represent the function; it is the overload set of the function name.

Your function

```
void foo(auto const &){}
```

appears to be using a concepts-esque extension of the language for a terse template function.  In standard C++ it would read:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T const &){}
```

A template function isn't a function.  It is an overload set of functions generated by that template.

An overload set of a function name *is not a C++ object*.  And the things you can pass to functions are C++ objects.

Now, when the overload set of a function name only names one function, the compiler automatically resolves the overload and gives you that function object.

When the overload set of a function name is converted to a pointer-to-function with a fixed signature, overload resolution kicks in and (hopefully) one is selected.

When calling `for_each`, however, the argument is not a specific fixed signature function pointer.  Instead it is a generic type parameter.  The compiler, at that point, has no way to resolve the overload set of the function name.  It is ambiguous which one you want.

There are two solutions.  One of them is to cast your function overload set into a specific function pointer.  This requires you are explicit.

A second one is top wrap your overload set into a single object.  You can do this with a manual function object with a template `operator()`, or in C++14 you can do this:

```
#define OVERLOADS_OF(...) \
   [](auto&&...args) \
   noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__(decltype(args)(args)...))) \
   ->decltype( __VA_ARGS__(decltype(args)(args)...) ) \
   { return __VA_ARGS__(decltype(args)(args)...); }
```

which builds a stateless lambda representing the overloads of a global function name.

So:

```
void foo(auto const &){}

auto const rng{ranges::view::all(v)};
ranges::for_each(rng, OVERLOADS_OF(foo));
```

if you want to catch fewer corner cases, a simple:

```
void foo(auto const &){}

auto const rng{ranges::view::all(v)};
ranges::for_each(rng, [](auto&x){foo(x);});
```

also works in this specific case.

As an aside, there was a C++20 proposal to replace `OVERLOADS_OF(foo)` with `[](auto&&...args)=>foo(decltype(args)(args)...)` (generating the same effect as the macro would).  Sadly, the `decltype` and `noexcept` features where voted down.

Comment: *"Sadly, the `decltype` and `noexcept` features where voted down."* Too soon. **:(**

Comment: Thank you. `#define OVERLOADS_OF(...)` looks scary - macros plus forward referenced variadic auto. o_O

Comment: @nikitablack Well, it tries to be complete.  Notice that `[](auto&x){foo(x);}` solves your problem in this specific case; `OVERLOADS_OF` just solves almost *every* corner case we can all in one spot.

Comment: I wouldn't say it was "voted down." I was under the impression that I just had to come back with a better paper (my proposal, btw). Also what I really wanted was something like `[](args...) => foo(>>args...)`, but it still needs a lot of work, we'll see what happens.

Comment: @Barry I dunno.  Having to name `args` twice violates DRY.  How about `[]=>foo(>>@...)`, where `@` is an implicit parameter pack of the arguments of the `auto&&...` arguments.  (I kid)